# Table responsive to textarea

Tags: html, css, html-table, textarea

How can I get the tbody height to change with the textbox height. Rather than the textbox getting a scroll bar.

---

Here is my HTML:

```
<table align="center" width="80%" border="1">
    <tbody class="tbody1">
//text entries - see fiddle
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="tbody2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="1" style="width:100%" class="wide boxsizingBorder" autocomplete="off" name="txt" type="text" id="usermsg" value=""></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the css:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
.boxsizingBorder {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
table {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tbody1{
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
}
.tbody2{
    margin: 0;
}
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CA9a/)

---

When I enter text into the text area it creates a scroll bar I want the tbody height to increase to a maximum of 25% and then scroll instead. Like how facebook does.

How could I do this?

Comment: If you look for a pure HTML/CSS solution, I'd have to disappoint you, you can't. When you're willing to use Javascript (jQuery) you might want to look into [jQuery autogrow plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/).

Comment: I am okay with using jquery! But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have tried [this](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf) but it doesnt work with box-sizing! Which is extremely annoying

Comment: @LinkinTED If you look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2CA9a/4/) you can use the corner thing to make it grow but when you enter text it doesn't grow